# Installing php5-openssl on Amazon SUSE SE 11 SP3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rpm, opensuse, zypper

I have a **SUSE ES 11 SP3 Amazon EC2 instance** and I need to **install the php5-openssl package**, but I'm **getting in trouble when using "zypper install"**. I should have upgraded the insance infrastructure update ([more details here](https://www.suse.com/communities/blog/2-months-warning-amazon-ec2-old-update-infrastructure-approaching-eol/)), but I missed the deadline and I am now with a useless instance, because I can not install anything .

Whenever **I use zypper install I got**:

```
Refreshing service 'susecloud'.
Problem retrieving the repository index file for service 'susecloud':
Download (curl) error for 'http://sa-east-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net/repo/repoindex.xml?cookies=0':
Error code: Connection failed
Error message: Couldn't resolve host 'sa-east-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net'

Check if the URI is valid and accessible.
Error building the cache:
[|] Valid metadata not found at specified URL(s)
Warning: Disabling repository 'php' because of the above error.
Download (curl) error for 'http://sa-east-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net/repo/update/SLE11-SDK-SP3-Pool/sle-11-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml':
Error code: Connection failed
Error message: Couldn't resolve host 'sa-east-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net'

Abort, retry, ignore? [a/r/i/? shows all options] (a): a
Problem retrieving files from 'SLE11-SDK-SP3-Pool'.
Download (curl) error for 'http://sa-east-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net/repo/update/SLE11-SDK-SP3-Pool/sle-11-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml':
Error code: Connection failed
Error message: Couldn't resolve host 'sa-east-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net'

Please see the above error message for a hint.
Warning: Disabling repository 'SLE11-SDK-SP3-Pool' because of the above error.
Download (curl) error for 'http://sa-east-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net/repo/update/SLE11-SDK-SP3-Updates/sle-11-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml':
Error code: Connection failed
Error message: Couldn't resolve host 'sa-east-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net'
```

If I try updating the update infrascructure I got:

```
Adding repository 'tmp_instance_infrastructure_upgrade' [done]
Repository 'tmp_instance_infrastructure_upgrade' successfully added
Enabled: Yes
Autorefresh: No
GPG check: Yes
URI: dir:///usr/share/instance_infrastructure_upgrade/repo

Repository 'tmp_instance_infrastructure_upgrade' priority has been set to 1.
Retrieving repository 'tmp_instance_infrastructure_upgrade' metadata [done]
Building repository 'tmp_instance_infrastructure_upgrade' cache [done]
Specified repositories have been refreshed.
Refreshing service 'susecloud'.
Problem retrieving the repository index file for service 'susecloud':
Download (curl) error for 'http://sa-east-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net/repo/repoindex.xml?cookies=0':
Error code: Connection failed
Error message: Couldn't resolve host 'sa-east-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net'

Check if the URI is valid and accessible.
Error building the cache:
[|] Valid metadata not found at specified URL(s)
Warning: Disabling repository 'php' because of the above error.
Download (curl) error for 'http://sa-east-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net/repo/update/SLE11-SDK-SP3-Pool/sle-11-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml':
Error code: Connection failed
Error message: Couldn't resolve host 'sa-east-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net'

...

--> Updating packages failed
```

I tried to install each php5-openssl dependency, downloading each RPM and installing with **rpm -i**,  but every time I resolve one dependency another appears. I also tried the suse forum ([post here](https://forums.suse.com/showthread.php?7724-Zypper-Problem-retrieving-the-repository-index-file#post32759)) but with no success until now.

So my questions are:

1. Is there some way to fix zypper repositories manually? Even if only to install the php5-openssl package.
2. Is there some way to use RPM to manage the dependencies for php5-openssl?
3. Is there another alternative to install php5-openssl in my suse instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short:

1. you cannot fix these repositories; since they don't exist anymore (try browsing to http://sa-east-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net/).
2. `rpm` cannot look for dependencies because `rpm` does not use repositories (that's where zypper comes in). You can look for rpms on [the internet](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3), and then install the manually using `rpm`; but `rpm` won't locate the missing rpms.
3. Yes; as said in point 2; you can look for the rpms; download them and install them manually; or else you can even look for repositories that contain the rpms you want, and add that repository. However be careful with that; since those repositories probably aren't made for Amazon EC2. If you do this; try to find a repository as close as possible to suse 11 EC2...

Comment: The solution was to migrate the application to a new instance .